# Color background in a textbox expression

Tags: reporting-services

```
=IIF ((First(Fields!act.Value, "General_info") = "immidiate_act","RED",IIF ((First(Fields!act.Value, "General_info") = "potential_act", "BLACK",IIF ((First(Fields!act.Value, "General_info") = "appreciation_act","BLACK",)))
```

`When [BC30198] ')' expected. error`. This is my expression for color above and I keep getting an error code as follows when I try to run the report.

> The 'BackgroundColor' expression for the text box 'Textbox26' contains an error: [BC30198] ')' expected.
> The definition of the report '' is invalid.
> An error occurred during local report processing.**

I'm expecting the text box to colour a specific colour when an certain option is selected.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing to do with sql. Please try below code block:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!act.Value, "General_info") = "immidiate_act", "RED",
    IIF(First(Fields!act.Value, "General_info") = "potential_act", "BLACK",
        IIF(First(Fields!act.Value, "General_info") = "appreciation_act", "BLACK",    Nothing)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer by Kazi is correct but you might want to consider using `SWITCH()` rather then nested `IIF`s, they are easier to read in my opinion.

Try this.

```
=SWITCH (
    First(Fields!act.Value, "General_info") = "immidiate_act", "RED",    
    First(Fields!act.Value, "General_info") = "potential_act", "BLACK",
    First(Fields!act.Value, "General_info") = "appreciation_act", "BLACK",
    True, Nothing
    )
```

**Notes**:

- The `True` at the end acts like an else.
- Check you don't have a typo ("Immediate" not "immidiate")